# How to make all the delete href tags make work with java scripts if clicked in Django

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I have written a java script for the conformation box before deleting the comments. If user clicks delete, it should pop the box for delete conformation. If i have series of comments of same user, as i am printing the comments in loop the java script logic is staying with the first delete comment itself until i delete it. If i say no, and try to delete second comment, the java script logic is not function. Can any one help me with this issue. Should i need to place the java script logic some where else in the code. Does that recognize?

```
<div class="container">
<h2 class="text-center">User Comments</h2>

{% for comment in comments%}
   <p class="text-secondary text-center">{{ comment.created }}</p>
   <p> {{ comment.body }} </p>
   {% if comment.user == request.user.username %}
      <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'comment-update' comment.id %}">Update Comment</a>
      <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1"  id="delete-object" >Delete Comment
      <script type="text/javascript">
         document.getElementById("delete-object").onclick = function(){
            if (confirm('Delete the comment')){
                alert('hi');
                #Link to delete comment}}
      </script>

    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the same `id` to multiple `a` tags. The `id` must be unique in the document.

Try with someting like

```
<div class="container">
<h2 class="text-center">User Comments</h2>

{% for comment in comments%}
   <p class="text-secondary text-center">{{ comment.created }}</p>
   <p> {{ comment.body }} </p>
   {% if comment.user == request.user.username %}
      <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'comment-update' comment.id %}">Update Comment</a>
      <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1"  data-action="delete-object" >Delete Comment
      <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            deleteLinks = document.querySelectorAll('[data-action="delete-object"]')
            deleteLinks.forEach(link => {
                link.addEventListener('click', function() {
                    if (confirm('Delete the comment')) {
                        alert('hi')
                        # link to the comment
                    }
                })
            })
        })
      </script>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor % }
```